# Erro no GIT com Mac OS X: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open

Tags: git, osx

Estou tentando utilizado o GIT pelo terminal (**Mac OS X**), mas está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

```
$ git help
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

Já reinstalei o *command line tools* e o erro ainda persiste quando utilizo algum comando `git`

No meu `.bashrc` estou utilizando o seguinte *path*...:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib
```

...pois estou utilizando virtualenv e o ambiente virtual não estava conseguindo identificar o postgresql, já comentei esta linha e reiniciei a máquina e ainda continua o mesmo erro. Apesar de algumas soluções na internet, não achei uma que resolvesse minha questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, descobri que além do arquivo `.bashrc` havia o arquivo `.profile` com `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib`, comentei esta linha e o problema foi resolvido.

Obs: para não deixar de utilizar o DYLD para funcionar o postgresql, criei um fallback no '.profile':

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Com isso o caminho padrão `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib` fica funcionando (o que não acarreta problema no GIT) e ao mesmo tempo é possível utilizar o postgresql sem ter problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Tente apontar a variável para um caminho real da biblioteca do `iconv` em seu sistema.

Assumindo que o seu sistema possui uma versão da biblioteca em `/usr/lib` (no meu OS X Mavericks ela está lá, mas eu instalei um monte de coisas extras nele, então não tenho como confirmar se isso é padrão):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
```

Adicionalmente [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457333/664577) (e o comentário na [Chris.Zou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767033/chris-zou)) sugerem adicionar o local do executável do `iconv` ao começo do `PATH` também. Assumindo que você está usando a versão do Git instalada junto ao XCode, o caminho `/usr/bin` já possui alta prioridade, mas em instalações pelo *brew* isso pode resolver.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

E conforme o comentário, para instalações [através do site do Git](http://git-scm.com/download) isso pode ajudar:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: O problema mesmo foi porque eu tinha referenciado o DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH para outro caminho no arquivo `.profile`, mas valeu pela colaboração.

Comment: Opa, não vi que você tinha encontrado o problema de *"restos de caminhos"* do PostgrSQL quando postei. Vou deixar a resposta mesmo assim pois acredito que ela possa ajudar outros usuários na mesma situação.